# where is the option to enable MTP?

Tags: nexus-7, 4.4-kitkat, mtp

So, I had the notification record to enable mtp/foto mounting option. It's now disappeared and I'm not able to find it in the settings page.

Can you tell me where is the option to enable MTP?

(I know it's a stupid question I really can't find it)

Comment: For Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) users: [Marshmallow USB connection type](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/125140)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Nexus 7 2013, `Settings > Storage > Hamburger icon (top-right) > USB computer connection`.

Comment: *LOL* "Hamburger menu"! Hungry? I always thought Android uses "sweets" to name things. But that one (for settings etc.) was usually called "gear". Did that change with the Nexus 2013? Can we expect more *McDonalds Food items* in the UI sooner or later?

Comment: @Izzy Honestly, I don't know what it's called, but some people call it a hamburger icon, because it looks like one. Haha.

Comment: The official name is the [overflow icon](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html), but "hamburger menu" has definitely become a popular name for it.

Comment: although I have to say I even didn't noticed it before @geffchang's answer

Comment: I never had the option that I could find; I had to [dial *#7284# and then click the USB settings in the phone properties](http://www.mysolutions.it/changing-android-usb-computer-connection-settings/).

Comment: @Logos Which phone was that on?  I just tried out of curisosity and that doesn't work on my Nexus 4.

Comment: @MatthewRead: It was a Note II, running 4.2.2.  Doesn't seem to be working on Note III running 4.3.  There's [an app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.afp_group.software) that checks the manifest on your phone for what dialcodes are available.