# Cant copy files via USB onto Moto G after cyanogenmod installation

Tags: cyanogenmod, usb, 6.0-marshmallow

I have just flashed my Moto G 2013 and it is working fine, but when I connect it to my PC it opens up as an empty folder. The name of the phone is there and when I click on it...it is all empty. None of the folders show up and this is slightly weird. I tried to copy an mp3 anyway and it says "cant write to this location".

Any ideas what is causing this behaviour?

Comment: Have you unlocked the device (entered PIN/fingerprint etc.)? On all my Samsung phones it is like this to prevent unauthorized access to private files.

Comment: @GiantTree I used the pin of my sim card, but never had to do anything like that with my Moto G. Unlocking the device. Is it something new in marshmallow?

Comment: I don't know about that. Maybe someone who read the changelogs of AOSP knows more about that.

Comment: @GiantTree No worries. Appreciate the help though. 
So....in a nutshell: I did use my PIN to unlock the device. So, that cant be an issue. Plus the device has internal memory....so it should be a default setting that a PC recognizes that.

Comment: @GiantTree Found the solution. One must choose "file transfer" from the notification bar. :) Otherwise it will only charge the battery and wont do anything else.

Comment: There you go: [Android 6: connect as camera per default](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/127508)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browse file system from PC in marshmallow](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/126195)