# Where is the MTP and PTP option in Android 9?

Tags: motorola-moto-g, mtp

Where is the MTP and PTP option in Android 9?

I checked

[where is the option to enable MTP?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58397/where-is-the-option-to-enable-mtp)

and it's not there.

I have a Moto G7 Power. I don't know if that makes a difference.

I see there is a command line option [How Do I change from PTP to MTP mode? Cannot find options in settings](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120026/how-do-i-change-from-ptp-to-mtp-mode-cannot-find-options-in-settings)

But i'm looking for the GUI option

I think they moved it from settiings..storage.  as it was there on an old phone.
I tried tapping build number 7 times, I can't see developer options.

Answer (score 1):

an answer from barlop https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device/18515360#18515360 mentions that it's now in developer options

i can see developer options now, (And FWIW I turned on USB debugging).  but they moved the sectoin to MTP  from the 'input' section of developer options to elsewhere

To find the USB options now, there is a search within developer options, search for USB. Now it comes under "default USB configuration"

and you see USB controlled by, or USB preferences.. And it's there

**update 2020**
And if PTP is listed but not MTP, then maybe what android may refer to as "File transfer" is the same as MTP. See my comment  [PTP but not MTP](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/98106/ptp-but-not-mtp)   , this link https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/ says "file transfer (MTP)” mode"   which suggests to me that they may be the same. And BTW to install adb you probably also need the driver from the android sdk as mentioned https://windowsreport.com/windows-unable-install-adb-interface/ so you don't get a yellow exclamation mark for adb under "other devices" in device manager.

Comment: Where are the dev options on a Samsung Galaxy Table Android 9?

Comment: @user3123159 I don't think it's phone specific , you'd get them the same way on any android phone it's a bit ridiculous but these are the instructions to get it  and yeah it involves tapping an option 7 times https://postimg.cc/sQDct088