# Why don't I have MTP option in the USB menu

Tags: usb, mtp

I used to be able to use the phone for debugging.
Now I have USB debugging enabled, and in it threr is a menu for default USB configuration. But it doesn't have an MTP option. The other options don't enable debugging either.

[image: USB menu]

I see in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5B8KdbH5Do that it should have other options.

(Checked [Where is the MTP and PTP option in Android 9?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213059/where-is-the-mtp-and-ptp-option-in-android-9) and older topics.)

Answer (score 2):

"Transferring files" means "MTP" and "Transferring images" means "PTP". I guess, to make the functionality of MTP and PTP meaningful to a larger set of people, the words were replaced with something that would make sense to anyone instantly on reading the new labels.

In the future, perhaps "USB tethering" might also get replaced with "Share Internet over USB" or something.